# How to get the number of children for a specific value in firebase database android?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app for android. I would like to get the number of children for a specific value in the firebase database. Then after the user clicks on a button, it will take that data convert it to a percentage, and display it in a textview. I can get the amount of children for each value and printing it to the monitor but when I use the same code and put it in a textview it prints out the last line, not all of it. So my question is how can I get the number of children for a specific value and have it be "compatible" with a textview.

Comment: Your code would help here

Answer (score 7):

[`datasnapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) method returns the  count which you will get in the observer you added to your database reference.

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to [getChildrenCount()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount())? It returns the number of immediate children in your reference. The return type is long so it will be easily manipulate the value, or display it on your textView.